# MS Access MDB query with VBScript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I can look up ALL the records from images with a VBScript:

```
cn.Execute "SELECT * INTO [text;HDR=Yes;Database=" & exportDir & _
";CharacterSet=65001]." & exportFile & " FROM IMAGES"
```

This works perfectly. However, I want to narrow down that search from all the records to just the ones where column B (ProjectName) == "spoon"

```
Dim projName
projName = "spoon"
cn.Execute "SELECT * INTO [text;HDR=Yes;Database=" & exportDir & _
";CharacterSet=65001]." & exportFile & " FROM IMAGES" & " WHERE ProjectName=" & projName
```

But I get the error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Mu SQL-fu is weak and not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Make sure you are putting quotes around proj, maybe this: `" WHERE ProjectName='" & proj & "'" `. This is necessary if projectname is a string variable, as you seem to imply

Comment: Another reason (besides SQL injection) to avoid string concatenation and use SQL parameters.

Comment: Another possible problem: {Dim projName: proj = "spoon"}

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Although that doesn't look like the problem here, as the OP is using `proj` in the SQL statement, not `projName`.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I missed that one thanks - updated code!

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest - but you still use "proj" in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude (and reduce slightly):

```
Dim projName
projName = "spoon"

cn.Execute "SELECT * INTO [text;HDR=Yes;Database=" & exportDir & _
";CharacterSet=65001]." & exportFile & " FROM IMAGES WHERE ProjectName='" & projName & "'"
```

Comment: Dim projName = "spoon" should be Dim projName : projName = "spoon"

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner: Right you are - I had VB.NET in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [@allen-wang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4408787/allen-wang) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746357/ms-access-mdb-query-with-vbscript/41758364#comment70685713_41746357) the reason for the error is lack of string value being identified as a string by encapsulating it in single quotes *(`'...'`)*.

However this and other issues such as SQL Injection weaknesses can be avoided by using the `ADODB.Command` to execute a Parameterised Query.

```
Dim cmd, sql, exportDir, exportFile

'Shouldn't be configurable outside this procedure.
exportDir = "..."
exportFile = "..."

Const adCmdText = 1
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adCmdVarChar = 200
Const adExecuteNoRecords = &H00000080

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
sql = "SELECT * INTO [text;HDR=Yes;Database=" & exportDir & _
";CharacterSet=65001]." & exportFile & " FROM IMAGES WHERE ProjectName = ?"
With cmd
  Set .ActiveConnection = cn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sql
  Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@ProjName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255))
  Call .Execute(, , adExecuteNoRecords)
End With
```

Just make sure that both `exportDir` and `exportFile` are not exposed or you leave the code open to SQL Injection.